# Molar mass of air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If we want to know the molar mass of let’s say air we know that air is 79% nitrogen and 21% oxygen. Why can we just calculate it like this:
0.79 x M(nitrogen) + 0.21 x (oxygen)?

Comment: What are the molecules in air?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have one mole of air, then its molar mass is the mass of this mole of air.

The one mole of air contains $0.79$ moles of nitrogen with a mass $0.79 M_{N_2}$ and $0.21$ moles of oxygen with a mass $0.21 M_{O_2}$ so the mass of our one mole of air is:

$$M_{air} = 0.79 M_{N_2} + 0.21 M_{O_2} $$

And that's the equation for the molar mass of air.

Comment: This was really helpful explanation!